# Alternetives to sendmail.exe to send confirmation emails?

Tags: php, forms, email, sendmail, confirmation

So I have been trying to get sendmail.exe to work on my local host server for a day now and it just won't do it.
Are there any alternatives to sendmail? Is there an online webservice which you can link from your .php-document to?

Comment: as a webservice, you can use mailgun ( very reliable, but you need a domain )

Answer (score 0):

These are the alternatives to sendmail
1.SMTP - Simple Mail Transport Protocol , which allows you to send emails using an smtp account on a supported mail server, This has many benefits than others, but you need to build your own mail server

2.Imap : Though Imap can be used to send email message, it is mostly not considered due to it complex nature (php_imap)

3.Online Services : If you cant create a mail server or dont have time to manage a mail server and its headaches , there are very good online services which provides support for SMTP transactional email account, this is the most prefered and suitable way since there are support to help you, also some provide simple api / sdk which allows you to integrate within minutes. some providers are listed below:

MailGun

- Amazon SES
- Postmark
- Sparkpost
- SendinBlue
- SendGrid
- Elastic
- Email
- Pepipost
- Mailjet
- Mailtrap.io (for testing your emails during development before going live)